# How to use marked plugins in Vue3 project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, javascript-marked

I have tried to use marked plugin in my Vue.js apps.
Installed marked@4.0.8, compiled is nothing problem.
But in browser, any contents showed.
I used vite to make Vue project.
Also, I referred [this site.](https://v3.vuejs.org/examples/markdown.html)

So my test code like that.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ markdown }}
  </div>
  <div v-html="markdownToHtml"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import marked from "marked";
const markdown = ref("# hello");
const markdownToHtml = computed(() => {
  return marked(markdown.value);
});
</script>
```

and error code in console at browser like that.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/marked.js?v=f8c9698b' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

How do I correctly use marked in Vue.js project?
Does anyone advise me,please?

Comment: it [exports a function](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/blob/master/src/marked.js#L21) so use `import { marked } from 'marked';`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need import the library as

`import { marked } from 'marked'`

and use like `marked.parse(markdown.value)`